# Center within first 2 columns, of a 3 column table?

Tags: html

My table has 2 rows with 3 columns, followed by a submit button. I would like the submit button to be in the center of the first 2 columns, but instead it is in the center of the 3 columns. How can I center it within the first 2 column?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Label 1:</td>
    <td align="left"><input type="text" name="input1"></td>
    <td> <a href="alink">a link</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Label 2:</td>
    <td align="left"><input type="text" name="input2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Make the cell span only 2 columns, and add another empty cell after it …?

Comment: Don't use tables for layouts. Not even for forms. Use labels and input types and use flexbox to center your content.

Comment: Terrible code btw., using outdated HTML attributes for styling, and a table to structure what is not really tabular data to begin with ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll need three columns in your last row, merging the first two with `colspan`. Also, don't use the deprecated `align` attribute.

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Label 1:</td>
    <td align="left"><input type="text" name="input1"></td>
    <td> <a href="alink">a link</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Label 2:</td>
    <td align="left"><input type="text" name="input2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="center"><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```